# Problem in WSL `openSUSE-Tumbleweed`, Unable to redirect to any site after installing wslutilities?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opensuse

I've been using WSL `openSUSE-Tumbleweed` as my goto terminal for software development. I use `GitHub CLI` a lot while working on the project. So I installed [wslutilities](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) for directly redirecting to the site. But for sometime wsl is giving me this problem while redirecting to site. As You can see from the screenshot below:

```
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start https\github.com\harshv5094\bio
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

exit status 4
```

I think it something has to do with powershell. If someone is facing the same issue could you give me the solution as to how to fix it.

I didn't tried anything as to how to solve this problem. But I completely uninstalled and reinstalled the [wslutilities](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu), But the problem still persist.